# Speed up LEFT JOIN with OR operator in ON clause

Tags: mysql, rdbms

I have a query that uses a LEFT JOIN with an OR operator within the ON clause. When commenting out the OR operator the query runs in ~150ms. With the OR operator kept in the query takes over 80s to run. Does anyone know how to speed this up? Details below.

```
supplier_responses
+----+-------------+-------------+----------+-------+
| id | internal_id | supplier_id | supplier | price |
+----+-------------+-------------+----------+-------+
| 1  | 100         | 100         | poggle   | 10    |
| 2  | 101         | 101         | poggle   | 15    |
| 3  | 102         | 290         | lello    | 12    |
| 4  | 103         | 370         | chugs    | 10    |
| .. | ...         | ...         | ...      | ...   |
+----+-------------+-------------+----------+-------+
Indexes on internal_id, supplier_id, supplier.

supplier_updates
+----+-------------+-------------+----------+--------+--------------+
| id | internal_id | supplier_id | supplier | status | timestamp    |
+----+-------------+-------------+----------+--------+--------------+
| 1  | 100         | 100         | poggle   | 80     | 2019-01-15...|
| 2  | 100         | 100         | poggle   | 100    | 2019-01-16...|
| 3  | null        | 290         | lello    | 80     | 2019-01-16...|
| 4  | 107         | 107         | poggle   | 80     | 2019-01-17...|
| 5  | 112         | null        | chugs    | 100    | 2019-01-17...|
| 6  | null        | 100         | lello    | 100    | 2019-01-18...|
| .. | ...         | ...         | ...      | ...    | ...          |
+----+-------------+-------------+----------+--------+--------------+
Indexes on internal_id, supplier_id, supplier, timestamp.
```

For "poggle" internal_id and supplier_id will be identical.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   supplier_responses sr 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
                  FROM   supplier_updates su 
                         LEFT JOIN (SELECT supplier supplier_name, 
                                           COALESCE(internal_id, supplier_id) latest_id, 
                                           Max(timestamp) latest_timestamp 
                                    FROM   supplier_updates 
                                    GROUP  BY supplier_name, 
                                              supplier_id) suLatest 
                                ON suLatest.supplier_name = su.supplier 
                                   AND suLatest.latest_timestamp = su.timestamp 
                                   AND suLatest.latest_id = 
                                       COALESCE(su.internal_id, 
                                       supplier_id) 
                 ) su 
              ON ( sr.supplier = su.supplier 
                   AND sr.internal_id = su.internal_id ) 
                  OR ( sr.supplier = su.supplier 
                       AND sr.supplier_id = su.supplier_id ) 
ORDER  BY su.timestamp_at ASC;
```

Comment: If `supplier_id` and `supplier` are 1:1, then that pair should not show up in multiple tables.  Please redo the schema, then the query, _then_ we can continue with a fresh Q&A.

Comment: Apologies Rick, in changing the headings of the tables/columns to simplify it for SE, I'd messed up the query. I've just edited the query. Hopefully it should now be clear supplier_id and supplier are not the same.

Comment: But if `supplier_id = 100` always refers to `supplier = 'poggle'`, then that mapping should be in only one table.

Comment: `supplier_id = 100` won't always refer to `supplier = 'poggle'`. You could also have a `supplier_id = 100` referring to another another supplier. Just updated the question to provide an example.

Comment: Sorry, the convention of `xx_id` and `xx` (or `xx_name`) confused me.

Comment: Yeah my fault, it is a little unclear!

Answer (score 2):

An `OR` in a join predicate like that can force scans because, like many uses of functions, the result isn't [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

Assuming appropriate indexes are in place, you can usually use a `UNION` instead to avoid the scanning, so:

```
   SELECT * 
     FROM supplier_responses sr 
LEFT JOIN supplier_updates su 
       ON ( sr.supplier = su.supplier AND sr.internal_id = su.internal_id ) 
       OR ( sr.supplier = su.supplier AND sr.supplier_id = su.supplier_id ) 
ORDER  BY su.timestamp_at ASC;
```

becomes:

```
   SELECT * 
     FROM supplier_responses sr 
LEFT JOIN supplier_updates su 
       ON ( sr.supplier = su.supplier AND sr.internal_id = su.internal_id ) 
    UNION
   SELECT * 
     FROM supplier_responses sr 
LEFT JOIN supplier_updates su 
       ON ( sr.supplier = su.supplier AND sr.supplier_id = su.supplier_id ) 
 ORDER BY timestamp_at ASC;
```

This looks like more work, but if each or the selects is much faster because they are properly indexed for and the `OR` is otherwise forcing indexes or whole tables to be scanned it will be significantly less work for the database engine to process.

If you know there won't be duplicates between the two `SELECT` outputs (rows where both `sr.supplier = su.supplier AND sr.internal_id = su.internal_id` and `sr.supplier = su.supplier AND sr.supplier_id = su.supplier_id` match) you can speed things up further using `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` which will save an extra sort operation (which would potentially end up spooling to disk).

I simplified your example a bit for brevity. Your sub-select for the `su` derived table may need to be broken out as a CTE or view to avoid doubling up that code (which could encourage partial edit bugs later). Of course that sub-query itself and it's sub-sub-query may cause performance issues depending on how bright the mySQL query planner is, especially as it is now hit twice, but I've stuck to dealing specifically with the `JOIN ... ON ... OR ...` issue.

Answer (score 0):

- Change `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN` unless you really need `LEFT`.
- Clean up things like `( sr.supplier_id = su.supplier_id AND sr.supplier_id = su.supplier_id )`
- Change the `OR` into a `UNION` (with a lot of rewriting)
- Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (so we can see if you have suitable indexes)
- Don't leave out the rest of the conditions -- they may be part of the problem.
- Improve the prettyprinting, perhaps

like this:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  supplier_responses sr
    LEFT JOIN  
        (
        SELECT  *
            FROM  supplier_updates su
            LEFT JOIN  
                (
                SELECT  supplier_id supplierId,
                        coalesce(internal_id, supplier_id) latest_id,
                        Max(timestamp) latest_timestamp
                    FROM  supplier_updates
                    GROUP BY  supplier_id, supplier_id
                ) suLatest  ON suLatest.supplierId = su.supplier_id
                         AND  suLatest.latest_timestamp = su.timestamp
                         AND  suLatest.latest_id = coalesce(su.internal_id, supplier_id)
        ) su  ON ( sr.supplier_id = su.supplier_id
              AND  sr.internal_id = su.internal_id 
                 )
      OR  (        sr.supplier_id = su.supplier_id
              AND  sr.supplier_id = su.supplier_id 
          ) --
    WHERE  some clause...
    ORDER BY  su.timestamp_at ASC;
```

Perhaps a composite index like `INDEX(supplier_id, internal_id)` would be beneficial.

Comment: @Kondybas - yeah,tired...

Comment: @Rick James, thanks for your answer. I've indexed the appropriate columns and I've also tested with the conditions. Going through block by block, it's just the OR operator that's slowing it. I don't suppose you have any tips on rewriting with union and/or with a composite index? I've tried but with no luck!

Comment: @Rick James, noted on your 2nd point. It was a mistake in rewriting it on here, just edited the query to what it should be.